# Adding javascript to an extended django template for google analytics

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a nice little index.html file,  it is an extended template and its parent is a base.html file (well in my case base2.html).  I was trying to add a google analytics code snippet to some files on my site and it turns out, if I add anything in the  tag on my extended templates, it is like the script code is ignored.   Is there something I am doing wrong?  I know I can add it just fine to base2.html, but then that would track for ever single hit since that is the parent for a lot of my pages on the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without seeing the `base2.html` and `index.html`, it's pretty tough to answer, but the most likely culprit is that you forgot to put the `<script></script>` inside of a `{% block %}` that exists in the parent template. Remember that for [template inheritance in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#id1), the parent defines a "skeleton" of all the blocks, and children must override those blocks— you can use `{{ block.super }}` to inherit all of the parent template's content for that block, then add any additional content. Any content in the child template that is not in a block in the parent "skeleton" template that it's extending doesn't get rendered.

```
# base2.html
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% block footer_scripts %}
    <script src="foobar"> ...</script>
    {% endblock footer_scripts %}
</body>
```

If you were to just add this, it wouldn't work:

```
# index.html - DOES NOT WORK
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
<script>
// GA javascript
</script>
```

You need to include it in a block:

```
# index.html - DOES WORK
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% block footer_scripts %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script>
    // GA javascript
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It is important that the {% block footer_scripts %} does NOT go inside the {% block content %}. If you do that then the scripts will load twice and break some toggle functionalities.