# How to use JavaScript variable as django tags template parameter?

Tags: javascript, python, django, templatetags

f I use the code as follows it works:

```js
function filter() {
  var assuntos = document.getElementById("assuntos").value
  var data = '{{ "CONTRATOS"|filter_assuntos }}';
  change(data);
};
```

but how do I use my `assuntos` variable instead of`CONTRATOS`?

Comment: you can't. The template is processed server side. Javascript is client side. They cannot interact

Comment: To expand on @MattEllen answer, you can render the javascript on the backend like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814002/adding-javascript-to-an-extended-django-template-for-google-analytics or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717059/how-to-use-use-a-django-variable-in-html-script-tag